# Does not appear sales cloud console in developer org

Tags: service-cloud-console, sales-cloud

I have selected the service cloud user´s option on user's record, but does not appear the  services cloud console app, neither the sales cloud console app in my developer org

Answer (score 1):

To use the console, you'll need to create a console app and give permission to users in your organization to view the app.

See: [Create a Salesforce Console App](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_define_app.htm&language=en_US)